# The tightest upper bound on $-\left\langle B(y-x),\nabla f(A x)\right\rangle$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ convex function with Hessian $H$ such that $lI\mathcal\le H(x)\le LI,\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then it is easy to show that $$f(x)-f(y)+\frac{l}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2\le-\langle y-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle\le f(x)-f(y)+\frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $l_2$ norm. I need to find an upper bound on the following expression $$-\left\langle B(y-x),\nabla f(A x)\right\rangle$$ where $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Using the preceding inequalities I could derive the following bound:$$-\left\langle B(y-x),\nabla f(A x)\right\rangle\le f(Bx)-f(By)+\frac{L}{2}\|By-Ax\|_2^2-\frac{l}{2}\|Bx-Ax\|_2^2$$ However, though the LHS of the inequality beocmes $0$ when $x=y$, the RHS doesn not, in general, which makes me conclude that this must be a loose inequality.

> Can anybody help refer me to any existing technique that might help me finding the tightest inequality?

Please **do not** provide a full answer, and give only suggestions, or references to useful techniques. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $F$ defined?

Comment: $f$ is convex and double differentiable as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: $f$ and $F$ are the same then? Is there a specific reason why you are using both lowercase and uppercase to denote the same thing?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that is a typo. I am correcting it now.